# Import into top level scope in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a series of files with variable definitions in the following directory arrangement:

```
+ ProjectDir
| main.py
- locations
    Location1.py
    Location2.py
```

Each location file defines variables with different values:

```
description = "Description of Location"
startpoint = (Lat1, Long1)
waypoints = [(Lat2, Long2), (Lat3, Long3)]
```

The number of waypoints in each location may be different (i.e. `waypoints` list will be different lengths), but the variable names will always be identical.

I want to have the following (example) behavior in `main.py`:

```
from locations import Location1
print(f'Starting point for {} is: {}, {}'.format(description, startpoint.Lat1, startpoint.Long1))
```

i.e. I don't want to have to use `Location1.description` or `Location1.startpoint.lat1`. Is this possible?

Comment: You typically don't want to pollute your global namespace with extra imports. Is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: I will be working with only one location in any given run of the script. They aren't extra imports so much as they are different values for global variables that I am working with. Once the location is selected (imported), it won't change until the next time I run this script, which could be days or weeks later.

Comment: You can use a starred import, `from locations.Location1 import *` or, maybe better practice, `from locations.Location1 import description, startpoint, waypoints`